# How to change cursor in Unity?

Tags: 11.04, unity, cursor

As we have to have active compiz with Unity, I can't change the color, size, etc. of the cursor.

Is there any way for do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a known bug in compiz see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/compiz/+bug/141500.

I found a workaround that works great for me on the bug page.

1. Create a file
2. Mark it as executable (Right Click > Properties > Permissions > Allow executing file as program)
3. Open in gedit and paste the following

   ```
   #!/bin/bash

   mkdir -p $HOME/.icons/default
   CURSOR_THEME=$(gconftool -g /desktop/gnome/peripherals/mouse/cursor_theme)
   echo "[Icon Theme]
   Inherits = $CURSOR_THEME" > $HOME/.icons/default/index.theme
   echo "Compiz will be restarted to enable this. Please stand by."
   compiz --replace &
   ```

Then Just run that file every time you change your mouse theme.

Comment: This works great, with the only side-effect being that I have to restart my user session for compiz/unity to recover properly.

Answer (score 2):

Edit `/usr/share/icons/default/index.theme` to include the name of the new theme and restart compiz. You will also need to choose the icon theme in `gnome-appearance-properties` for each user, in order to get certain programs like firefox and gdm to behave.

Answer (score 0):

The way I got round this was to remove the default cursor theme.

Copy & paste this command into Terminal

```
sudo apt-get remove dmz-cursor-theme
```

Now the new cursor theme you want will be applied.

Comment: The black cursos was remove. But then it does nothing.