# How can I increase the mouse cursor size and change its color in Unity?

Tags: unity, gnome, mouse, cursor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change cursor in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35789/how-to-change-cursor-in-unity)

How can I increase the mouse cursor size? I use my computer plugged to a TV far from me. I need to increase the mouse cursor to make it visible. Also I'd like to change it to a darker color as I used to do easily in Gnome 2. I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with Unity and didn't find this config.

Comment: And a video about setting the size: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yxfa2fXJ1Wc